# jquery hide multiple rows based on class

Tags: jquery, asp-classic, ado

I have a database output from a record set into a table like this:

```
Response.Write "<TR class=data>"
For i = 0 to rs.Fields.Count
if i < 4 then
    if i = 0 or i = 1 or i = 2 then
        response.Write "<td align=center>" & rs.Fields(i) & "</td>"
    else
        response.Write "<td align=center class="&rs.Fields(i)&"><div id=thisone>" & rs.Fields(i) & "</div></td>"
    end if
end if
Next
Response.write "</TR>"
```

As you can see I've set up a class name that is equal to the 4th item in the row (in this case, the username).  What I'd like to do is hide all rows with the same username if the end user clicks anywhere in the row.

so far, what i have is this:

```
    <script>
var username;

$(document).ready(function(){

    $("TR.data").click(function () { 
       username = $(this).find('td:last').text();
       alert(username);

       $(this).each(function(object){
           if($(this).find('td:last').text() == username){
               object.hide();
           }
       });
    });   
});
</script>
```

I'm able to get the username correctly stored, but when i try to iterate through the table to find other rows with that username, I can't seem to hide them.  I think maybe I need to use the parent() method, but everything I've tried has failed.

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
$("TR.data").click(function () { 
   var username = $(this).find('td:last').text();

   $("TR.data:contains('"+username+"')").hide();

});
```

Comment: Another great answer.  I didn't know about the contains() method.  Much appreciated!

Comment: ah!  new to the site.  i didn't know how.

Comment: for anyone looking to do the opposite (eg: click a row and make all OTHER rows disappear) you can use the method "not()".  Here's the example I used:

$("TR.data").not(":contains("+username+")").fadeOut(500);

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 $('.yourclass').css('display', 'none');
```

This will find all elements with the given class name and apply a display: none style to each of them.

Comment: Perfect!  The only thing I had to change was adding in .parent() before the css because it was only hiding the <td> rather than the whole row.  Definitely easier than what I was trying. Thanks much!

Comment: rather than doing parent() I tend to prefer .closest('tr'), that way you always know that you will be hiding the row, regardless of what was clciked